# How to discard minutes in rails select_time_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to ask is there a way to discard minutes in select_time_tag I just want to show hours. I want something like this.

```
<%= select_time_tag "opening", :discard_minutes=> true %>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the following in your form:

```
time_select :opening, :discard_minute=> true
```

Comment: I have already applied this but I think its good to use proper way to fill a time record.

Comment: Updated answer with a rails form helper answer